# WebAPI multiTenant authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I have an issue with a current internal API that is to be made private to our clients.  The DB holds multiple client data.

We have multiple clients who in turn have lots of users.

Our requirement is to authorize only the client (how they implement users isn't our problem), However once authenticated they will only have access to there client data.

I was going to create a dummy c# MVC5 web app that will act as a client consuming our web api.

Sorry if this is difficult to explain, head currently spinning on the requirement with no spec.

**Question**

I have a personnel app that is hosted on azure that generates a client ID and secret and an app that uses this to grab a token, can i do the same in just web api 2 (non azure)? But also pass some sort of identifier saying this client is client "A" or "B"

Comment: Put a claim into the Token to identify which tennant/client it is, then swap context base on that. This question might be put on hold as it's not really a specific coding problem that needs solving, it's more architectural

Comment: would this question be better suited on a different stack?